# How to add a hyperlink in overleaf?

Tags: html, latex

I have created my resume using overleaf.com. The topmost part of the resume is shown in the image. Can anyone please tell me how I can add a hyperlink to my mail ID and my LinkedIn profile using overleaf.com.

[[image: My resume [1]]

Comment: I have created my resume using overleaf.com. The topmost part of the resume is shown in the image. Can anyone please tell me how I can add a hyperlink to my mail ID and my LinkedIn profile using overleaf.com.

Comment: Without knowing which template you use for your resume, this is impossible to answer

Answer (score 5):

You should try the hypperref package.

It allows to embed hyperlinks.

You can find documentation here
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks
but there are essentially two important commands

`\href{url}{text}` makes `text` clickable and creates a link to `url`.

`\url={url}` inserts a clickable url

Here is an example use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
You can have a look at \href{http://my.site.com}{my site} or contact me on 
\url{https://www.linkedin.com/my-profile}. 
\end{document}
```

and the output

[image]

Link appearance can be customized.

Comment: but when I type in the above command and when I recompile, it's printing the new line on the left side of the screen. Whereas I want it to be in the middle of the page.

Comment: and also why am I not able to add a fourth \adress below \name field? Only 3 \address fields are being visible.

Comment: I do not know what style you use for your CV and I cant answer. Maybe you should ask another question, while giving all the required details, the source code, etc. For retrieval, it is better to have questions on a unique subject. For the same reason, do not forget to validate posts that answer your questions.